# Redirect traffic through the server

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, tunneling, traffic

My task is to redirect traffic (port range) through the server. Here is the schema:

[image]

**Why NAT is not appropriate here:** If NAT is set to "Tunnel Server", then all users will be assigned the same IP.

**What I need:** I want that when user connects to "Tunnel server" he was automatically redirected to "Server" and IP of this user was not changed. The endpoint must see the real IP of the user.

[image]

**Edit:**
Now I have this NAT rules:

```
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $SRV_IP -p tcp --dport 25550:25580 -j DNAT --to-destination $MC_IP
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25550:25580 -o eth0 -d $MC_IP -j SNAT --to-source $SRV_IP
$IPT -A FORWARD -d $MC_IP -p tcp --dport 25550:25580 -j ACCEPT
```

And the endpoint server show the IP of "Tunnel server" on every client.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 10.* addresses internally so you *must* use NAT if you want them reachable from the Internet in general.

Create a DNAT (Destination NAT, or Port Forwarding) rule on the Tunnel Server that directs users to the corresponding port on your Server.

---

UPDATE in response to the amendment in the Question that shows the output from `iptables`.

You say that you need the SNAT rule in order to have the users connect to the Server 10.10.0.1. You can remove that rule provided you add a default route on the Server that has your Tunnel Server 10.10.0.3 as the gateway. This will define the return path for packets originating on the Internet.

```
route add -net default gw 10.10.0.3
```

Comment: Server also have public IP. NAT modify client IP, but I need to get it real IP.

Comment: user2058653 You would have real client IPs. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: Look at my NAT rules, I have edited my post. My server say that every user have the same IP as "Tunnel server".

Comment: Remove the SNAT rule, the DNAT is enough as long as the default route on the destination system is back via the same route.

Comment: Without SNAT it don't work.

Comment: @User2058653 then you need to fix your routing tables so that there is a route back out to the Internet

Comment: Nothig changed, tried to do it in many ways, but without SNAT or MASCERADE rule it don't work.